# Angularjs variable set in method not changing the variable outside said method

Tags: angularjs

This is really strange ... So all of the sudden a variable I have set and re-set numerous times in my controller suddenly will no longer allow to be itself reset.

Controller:

```
$scope.classIndex = 0;

$scope.classNum = function(i){
  $scope.classIndex = i;
  //do other stuff with $scope.classIndex  
  //// This one wont update classIndex i.e. functions called with it always 
  ////show classindex as 0
}

$scope.viewClass = function(i){
  $scope.classIndex = i;
  //do other stuff with $scope.classIndex  //// BUT !!?? This one works fine
}
```

Html

```
////inside an ng repeat ... hence $index
<div class="btn-group col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" ng-show="options">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info btn-flat col-xs-6" ng-click="viewClass($index)"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> View </button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat col-xs-6" ng-click="classNum($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"> Delete</i></button>
</div>
```

So basically my view button shows the right item, but delete always deletes the item at index[0].

Any thoughts?

Edit: This was apparently a bug. I copied the code to a new file, uploaded to server and it suddenly began working again ...

Comment: I don't think that there's anything wrong with the code you posted above, problem could be elsewhere. It would be helpful if you could create a plunkr/fiddle showing this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant replicate the issue. Ive written thousands of variables but this is the first one to ever not assign when I write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are not using that variable in any Html page, ang using it in
>   only that js controller then do it in given way. **:**

```
var classIndex = 0;

$scope.classNum = function(i){
  classIndex = i;
  //do other stuff with $scope.classIndex  
  //// This one wont update classIndex i.e. functions called with it always 
  ////show classindex as 0
}

$scope.viewClass = function(i){
  classIndex = i;
  //do other stuff with $scope.classIndex  //// BUT !!?? This one works fine
}
```

- "$scope" is used when you want to bind data with html page, if you
  are using some data in js controller only then no need of that.

Comment: So if I am not binding data then I should just use var or direct declaration such as: classIndex = ....?